# Got Library not loaded error while setting up sfml

Tags: xcode, sfml, apple-m1, sigabrt

I am trying to compile simple code that will show me a window by using Xcode with my Mac. Everything seems to work and I get "Build Succeeded". But then nothing happens and I get the message:

```
(Thread 1: signal SIGABRT)

dyld[4523]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libsfml-audio.2.6.dylib

Referenced from: <7D1C4D6C-E8F9-3EE8-8D07-424CDBBB821D> /Users/harishs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sfml_hello-eqxoyoymdoqqvoeulpeflapfoayw/Build/Products/Debug/sfml_hello

Reason: tried:
'/Users/harishs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/sfml_hello-eqxoyoymdoqqvoeulpeflapfoayw/Build/Products/Debug/libsfml-audio.2.6.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/system/introspection/libsfml-audio.2.6.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
```

But I have linked all my libraries as well as having them in usr/local...

Comment: Was able to compile the code using terminal works fine.